# How to create a small system to randomize file names on a USB stick?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I bought a USB stick and put like 700 songs on it, so that I can plug it into my car radio, put it on shuffle and never get tired of listening to the same songs over and over again.
Turns out the car radio stops at (of course) 256 songs, so it will not play the ones with a higher ID than that.

Now I thought it would be cool to have like a Raspberry Pi where I plug the USB stick in, hit a button and the songs on it just get random names. That way the first 256 songs will be different every time I do it.
I already worked with Raspberrys, so I would know how to do that, but I honestly don't want to buy a Raspberry Pi just for that. Is there a smaller, cheaper option to achieve the same? I have an Arduino nano, but that won't work, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a smartphone you can use OTG cables. That way you can read your usb stick to your smartphone and make a small script or app for your device to randomise the names

Comment: Thanks! How did I not think of that... ? Is it easy to read and change the USB data from an android app?

Comment: yes however it depends on which android phone you have, i cant say much for ios. Marking my answer as verified will be very helpful for me.